# How to specify available values for drop down menu

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing a SSRS report which prints the instructorid and instructor full name but for the selected criteria. For the report, I have to prompt a drop down menu. In available values section I chose specify values and added all the four labels

Parameter Drop Down
Instructor Type:
SYSTEMS, SOFTWARE,CYBERSECURITY,DATABASE

Criteria
if SYSTEMS is selected – instructor ID like ‘SYS%’
If CYBERSECURITY is selected – instructor ID like ‘SEC% or ‘MAL%’ or ‘CYB%’
if SOFTWARE is selected -   instructor ID like ‘SOFT%’
IF DATABASE is selected - instructor ID like ‘DATA%’

```
Query:
select instructorid, fullname
from instructor 
where instructorid like selected criteria

Result Query if SYSTEM is selected
select instructorid, fullname
from instructor 
where instructorid like 'SYS%'
```

Question:
If CYBERSECURITY is selected – instructor ID like ‘SEC% or ‘MAL%’ or ‘CYB%’ 
How do I add these values for my available values without creating another label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add more available values to accommodate the various instructor IDs. You'll need to adjust the query to handle it. For example, part of your `WHERE` clause would look like this:

```
WHERE (@Parameter = 'SYSTEMS' and instructorid like 'SYS%')
  OR (@Parameter = 'CYBERSECURITY' and (instructorid like 'SEC%' OR instructorid like 'MAL%' OR instructorid like 'CYB%'))
```

You can continue this structure to add more options. Watch your parentheses to make sure the logic holds up.

Comment: How can I display the Cyber security label in the drop down menu

Comment: I am also getting report item expressions can only refer to fields within current dataset scope  error

Comment: Those are separate issues. Available values for parameters always have a label associated with them. You can use whatever friendly description you want for the labels. I would recommend posting another question with more detail about your scope error. I didn't suggest any changes to your existing report, just the query.

Comment: @M.Doe Did you get your `WHERE` clause working with your dropdown?

Comment: I think I got it to work. I am editing the design a little bit